# Force text instead of HTML

Tags: php, html, webforms, textbox

I'm having the following problem: I have a page where a user inserts text inside a textarea and then I output the contents of that textarea in another page (php).

If the user decides to insert, for example input type="text" name="_name" (can't use < and > or the text won't show, which is exactly my problem) then when showing the output I will have a textbox shown. I want to force text only to appear. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to output some special HTML characters, you can use function `htmlspecialchars()`.

```
$textarea = '<input type="text" />';
echo htmlspecialchars($textarea);
```

This outputs `&lt;input type=&quot;text&quot; /&rt;`
It will be rendered properly as `<input type="text" />` by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to encode special HTML characters to their HTML entities (especially `<` to `&lt;` and `&` to `&amp;`).

Example:

```
<?php
echo "Pi is <4"; // HTML syntax error, '<' needs to be encoded properly
echo htmlspecialchars("Pi is <4"); // Ok, outputs 'Pi is &lt;4', which is proper HTML
```